# How to design and make thermal inkjet print head / nozzles

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, fluid-mechanics

I'm recently interested in print-heads, especially thermal inkjet print heads.
I would like to design a simple print head with nozzles in a row with no chambers, but only a straight linear pipe-like structure, and the heating resistors stuck on the side.

I'm quite lost here. I don't know what kind of material I should use, or what should be the diameter of the nozzle, and etc.

I want to look at the earliest version of thermal inkjet print heads but all that I can get in google patent is the latest, and high tech version of print heads that I can barely understand.

Can anyone tell me what to do, or where to look at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, read the May 1985 issue of the *HP Journal* magazine; it explains the construction of the very first thermal inkjet printhead that HP brought to market in March of 1984, which I helped design.

That printhead was called the *Thinkjet*; you can try googling on that.

I wrote extensively about printhead device physics and design during my 34 years in the inkjet field and would be happy to discuss your project with you. You can contact me directly through my website, www.nielsenkillowatt.com.

Comment: @J.Lee your question has landed in one of the best places IMHO.